# Hairy ball theorem : a counter example ?

Tags: differential-topology, proof-verification, riemann-surfaces, vector-bundles

Recall the hairy ball theorem : any continuous vector field on a sphere $S^n$ of even dimension must vanish at least once.

Now consider the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C} \cup \infty \simeq S^2$. Let $X(z)=(1+|z|^2) \frac{d}{dz}$. Then $X$ is a continuous, *complex* non-vanishing vector field of the Riemann sphere (unless I'm mistaken). You can check it doesn't vanish at infinity by using the coordinates $w=1/z$ for $w$ near $0$.

I guess that this does not contradict the hairy ball theorem because here we view $S^2$ as a complex manifold of complex dimension one instead of a real 2-manifold.

In particular, in the chart $z$, the expressions of the continuous vector fields on the Riemann sphere are exactly the $X = h(z) \frac{d}{dz}$ with $h$ a continuous complex-valued function which is $O(z^2)$ at infinity (there are no additional restriction like "it has to vanish at least once").

Am I being correct here ?

Comment: It doesn't vanish at infinity, but it's also not _continuous_ at infinity, at least at first glance.  (Intuitively, as we go off to infinity in various directions, the field _also_ goes off in those directions, so what direction it 'has' at infinity is dependent on what direction we used to get there.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be careful here. You're using a smooth section (but not a holomorphic one) of $T\Bbb CP^1\otimes\Bbb C$. But it is not continuous at $\infty$. When you change coordinates, as you suggested, using $w=1/z$, you get $X=-\big(w^2+\dfrac w{\overline w}\big)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial w}$, which, in fact, has no limiting value at $w=0$.

Comment: Thanks ! I should have written it down after all... So is this true : a vector field $X = h(z) d/dz$ is continuous at infinity iff $h(z)=az^2 + o(z^2)$, where $a$ is a complex constant ? It just seems weird that you can't find any continuous such function with $a \neq 0$ which doesn't vanish...

Comment: Yes, this seems correct. Note that it's different from requiring $h(z) = O(|z|^2)$.

Comment: OK, thank you !

Answer (score 9):

Although, as @Ted pointed out, your example isn't continuous at $\infty$, it's interesting to note that there *is* a smooth nonvanishing complex vector field on the Riemann sphere.  Here's an example:
$$
X = \left( 1-z^2\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + 
\left( 1+\overline z^2\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z}.
$$
This vanishes nowhere in $\mathbb C$. To see what happens at $\infty$, make the change of coordinates $z=1/w$. It ends up looking almost the same:
$$
X = \left( 1-w^2\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial w} -\left( 1+\overline w^2\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline w},
$$
which is smooth and nonvanishing at $w=0$.

What's going on here? Basically, a complex vector field can be thought of as a pair of real vector fields (the real and imaginary parts).  For a complex vector field to vanish, both its real and imaginary parts have to vanish.  So I just chose a smooth vector field on the sphere whose real part vanishes only at $\infty$ and whose imaginary part vanishes only at $0$.